# How to parse this file?

Tags: c++, parsing

I am trying to parse the following area file in order to get the total combinational area, noncombinational area, and total cell area, but I have been unsuccessful and feel like I have no idea how to do this. I tried reading in each value, but I keep getting errors:

So I want to be able to store the following values in three separate arrays:

20368.919640,
2050.360019,
22419.279659

Here is my file:

```
****************************************
Report : area
Design : mymodule
Version: F-2011.09-SP1
Date   : Sat Mar 28 17:00:30 2015
****************************************

Library(s) Used:

    PLEXPVT (File: /bin/comp/temp/tech.2.1/PLEXPVT-PLEXPVT-CDS_4.1/libs/PLEXPVT.25C.db)
    PLEXPVT (File: /bin/comp/temp/tech.2.1/PLEXPVT-PLEXPVT-CDS_6.0/libs/PLEXPVT.25C.db)

Number of ports:                          277
Number of nets:                          5905
Number of cells:                         5341
Number of combinational cells:           5092
Number of sequential cells:               249
Number of macros:                           0
Number of buf/inv:                        606
Number of references:                     212

Combinational area:       20368.919640
Noncombinational area:    2050.360019
Net Interconnect area:      undefined  (Wire load has zero net area)

Total cell area:          22419.279659
Total area:                 undefined

Hierarchical area distribution
------------------------------

                                  Global cell area            Local cell area
                                  -------------------  ----------------------------- 
Hierarchical cell                 Absolute    Percent  Combi-      Noncombi-  Black
                                  Total       Total    national    national   boxes   Design--------------------------------  ----------  -------  ----------  ---------  ------  ---------
mymodule                          22419.2797    100.0  20368.9196  2050.3600  0.0000  mymodule
--------------------------------  ----------  -------  ----------  ---------  ------  ---------
Total                                                  20368.9196  2050.3600  0.0000
```

Comment: I tried using the >> operator with the fid

Comment: For a person with that reputation/days on this site I would think that you should be able to post a better question

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is not to try to understand everything, but just focusing on the lines that contain the data you need; for example:

```
double comb=0, ncomb=0, tcell=0;
int comb_count=0, ncomb_count=0, tcell_count=0;

std::ifstream input(filename);
for (std::string L; std::getline(input, L);) {
    if (get_data(L, "Combinational area", &comb)) comb_count++;
    if (get_data(L, "Noncombinational area", &ncomb)) ncomb_count++;
    if (get_data(L, "Total cell area", &tcell)) tcell_count++;
}

if (comb_count==1 && ncomb_count==1 && tcell_count==1) {
    // The file contained exactly one of each
    vcomb.push_back(comb);
    vncomb.push_back(ncomb);
    vtcell.push_back(tcell);
} else {
    // Something was missing or data repeated
    ...
}
```

where `get_data` is simply

```
bool get_data(const std::string L,
              const std::string& prefix,
              double *v) {
    return (sscanf(L.c_str(), (prefix + ": %lf").c_str(), v) == 1);
}
```